# Delete n rows of table in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to keep my table have max 10 rows of record. I will run cronjob and check if a record exist in my table or not.

So to do that I will insert as many as possible records that aren't exist first, then delete the n numbers of row inserted to keep the row at maximum 10 row.

How do I write my DELETE query?

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make a simple request to collect the total number of row in the table. Then run your delete query by adding a LIMIT clause that equals the total number minus 10. for example for a table with 100 entries, assuming you want to delete the oldest first and that the table has a timestamp in a created_at attribute:

```
DELETE FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 90
```

Comment: asc is part of order by so its not required if you dont need to order the column. limit is the number of row deleted.

Comment: so the key is just order by, and delete the eldest 10 by using limit? but u use limit 90, what does that mean?

Comment: if I inserted 3 new row and I should delete.. limit 3 to keep the row has a max of 10 , correct?

Comment: Keep the limit to 10, if the difference between the total number of row and 10 is negative or 0, just do not delete anything i.e do not run the delete query.